# NodeJS Nginx run php

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

I want to setup a nginx server with node.js that works, but how can i run a php script in it.
i have try but i don't no how its work.

the code i now use is.

this is the code in node.js i use and i have nothing changed in the settings of nginx

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Server 1\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

but i don't no how i can use php in't 
i hope you guys could help me.

Comment: Why would you ever want to mix in the horrible PHP crap in something as nice as Node.js ?

Comment: Why would you ever want to mix in the horrible Node.JS with something as nice as Nginx?